# How to run Playwright test from Pycharm in headed mode

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, playwright, playwright-python

I'm using Python & Pytest to write Playwrite tests.
PyCharm is the my IDE.

When I'm debugging a test - I run it from the IDE (by pressing the play icon next to the test). I would like to be able to view the browser during the run in order to debug.

The problem is that when using the 'page' fixture - the default mode is headless.

I know that I can run the test from the CLI and add the flag '--headed', but I want to run headed also by running from the IDE.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible!
Just create or add to your pytest.ini file which should go in the root of the working directory.

Here is what the pytest.ini file could look like:

```
# content of pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = -v --browser chromium --headed --slowmo 2000
```

Having --headed in there is what gives you what you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: make sure you install 'pip3 install pytest-playwright' before you start in your python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Preferences, tab "Python Integrated Tools"
2. Set Default test runner as pytest
   [image: default test runner]
3. Go to edit configurations in the Run/Debug Configurations
   [image: Run/Debug configurations]
4. Add a new pytest configuration (plus sign)
5. Set "Target" as "Custom" and then write whatever flags you want to use in the "Additional Arguments" input field
   [image]